# Validate a POJO without using @Valid in Spring MVC

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I need to validate a POJO, **without** using the annotation `@Valid` as paramether of a method.

I'm stuck at this point:

```
    ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
    Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
    Set<ConstraintViolation<Menu>> constraintViolations=validator.validate(menu);
    //Menu is my Pojo

    if (!constraintViolations.isEmpty()) {
        Iterator itr = constraintViolations.iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext()){
            Object o = itr.next();
        }               
    }
```

It seems to work, since inside "itr" I have stuff like this::

`oConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='size must be between 3 and 50', propertyPath=titolo, rootBeanClass=class com.springgestioneerrori.model.Menu, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.Size.message}'}`

Now, my question is: how can I add "itr" values to BindingResult??? Probably I should cast something...somehow...

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Test
public void testBindingResult(BindingResult result,Set<ConstraintViolation<String>> violations){
    for (  ConstraintViolation<String> constraintViolation : violations) {
        ObjectError error=new ObjectError("object",constraintViolation.getMessage());
        result.addError(error);
    }
}
```

you should create object of type `ObjectError` [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/ObjectError.html) is a spring doc for the class and you should add it to binding result.